# SpringBoot with multi-project Gradle --> Main class name has not been configured and it could not be resolved

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I have the following project structure:

```
RootProject
├── lib
     └── src
          └── main
               └── java
                    └── ...
├── test-project
     └── src
          └── main
               └── java
                    └── ...

└── build.gradle
```

I trying to follow Gradle [best practices](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#multi_project_builds) for multi project builds, and therefore I describing the whole build process in single build.gradle file.

"RootProject" is just a root project without any code and its single purpose is to provide a single build.gradle for its subprojects: "lib" and "test-project".

"test-project" is a SpringBoot project (micro service) using "lib" as compile dependency.

My common build.gradle looks as the following:

```
plugins{
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.1.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.6.RELEASE'
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}


subprojects {

    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

    group = 'com.xxx.yyy'
    version = '1.0'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8
}


project(":lib"){

    apply plugin: 'java-library'

    dependencies {

        implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web'
        implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
        testImplementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test'
    }

    bootJar { enabled = false }
    jar { enabled = true }
}

project(":test-project"){

    apply plugin: 'java'

    dependencies {
        implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web'
        implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
        implementation project(":lib")
        implementation ('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
    }
}
```

Both "lib" and "test-project" are built successfully. However, when I trying to execute "bootJar" task on root project (which supposed to trigger "build" task on all subprojects) I getting the following error:

```
Main class name has not been configured and it could not be resolved
```

Any ideas?

Comment: if the main class is in your lib project and the spring-boot plugin in the test-project you need to configure the main class in the plugin. and just to be sure: the main class has the @SpringBootApplication annotation on it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**An intro on multi-project build best practices**

When you say:

> I trying to follow Gradle best practices for multi project builds, and therefore I describing the whole build process in single build.gradle file.

I don't think this is actually is a good practice, and this is not what is really recommended in[the guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html) you mentioned.

In the guide intro:

> While each subproject could configure itself in complete isolation of
> the other subprojects, it is common that subprojects share common
> traits. It is then usually preferable to share configurations among
> projects, so the same configuration affects several subprojects.

=> Indeed, common traits shared between subprojects should be configured in a central place in root project build.

Later in the guide (in [this section](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:project_jar_dependencies) ) there is a example with subprojects specific configuration defined in the root project script , but there is a note in the example description:

> All the build logic is in the build script of the root project.(2)
>
> (2):  We do this here, as it makes the layout a bit easier. **We usually put the project specific stuff into the build script of the respective projects.**

**Regarding your issue**

I make assumption that your `lib` project is a plain "simple" java lib project (no Spring or SpringBoot dependencies), and `test-project` is the project containing the SpringBoot application classes (specially the `@SpringBootApplication` main application class).
Following best practices described above, you should then have three distinct project build scripts:

- `root project`: used to defined common configuration share in subproject (java plugin configuration, repositories, shared dependencies, etc...)
- `lib` project : specific configuration for this lib project (java-library plugin, specific dependencies, ...)

  - there is no reason to apply `spring-boot` plugin to this sub-project, and this is actually the cause for your error "cannot find main class"
  - if this project has dependencies on Spring-core modules , you could simply apply the `io.spring.dependency-management` plugin (in this cas it would make sense to apply this dependecy plugin in the root project build, to use same Spring version in both subprojects)
- `test-project`project: configuration related to Spring Boot application (SpringBoot plugin and dependencies)

**Example**

*root project build*

```
ext{
    slf4jVersion = "1.7.25"
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: "java"
    // if both subprojects share some Spring related dependencies, apply the Spring `io.spring.dependency-management` here.

    group = 'com.xxx.yyy'
    version = '1.0'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

*'lib' project build*

```
plugins{
    id 'java-library'
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: slf4jVersion
    // lib dependencies
}
```

*'test-project' build*

```
plugins {     
    id "org.springframework.boot"  version "2.1.1.RELEASE"
}
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

dependencies {
    implementation project(":lib")
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    implementation ('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
    // ...
}
```

**EDIT** as per your comment:  if `lib` project requires Spring Data related stuff, apply the `io.spring.dependency-management` as follows ( see more details [in Spring reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#managing-dependencies-using-in-isolation))

```
plugins{
    id 'java-library'
    id "org.springframework.boot"  version "2.1.1.RELEASE" apply false
}
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin.BOM_COORDINATES
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: slf4jVersion
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa' 
    // lib dependencies
}
```

Comment: "lib" is a library having "common" (e.g reusable) code dealing with JPA. So, "lib" needs to have dependency in Spring but it not intended to be executable. The second project ("test-project") is referencing ("lib") as a compile dependency and intended to be executable (spring boot)

Comment: As I sais in my answer, in case you need some Spring related deps in `lib` you simply have to apply the `io.spring.dependency-management` plugin , not the 'spring-boot' plugin. I updated my answer.

Comment: "dependencyManagement" part was missing, now it does compile. Thank you

Comment: excellent answer of separation of concerns. and putting (only) the abstract SLF4J abstract jar in the "lower projects".  thank you.